Rolling an n-sided dice until reaching a cumulative sum
Suppose we have a problem of the sort

You have an $n$-sided dice. Each time you roll the dice you add its value to a sum. What is the expected number of rolls until your cumulative sum reaches $k$?

Namely, for $n = 2$, and $k = 45$, I expected the answer to be $30$, since the expected value is $(1+2)/2 = 1.5$ and $45 / 1.5 = 30$. However, upon numerical verification through Python the approximate answer is actually around $30.2222...$. Upon noting that it isn't $30$, I verified the exact answer to be the monstrous irreducible fraction $\frac{531,674,956,009,017}{17,592,186,044,416}$.
Where does this $0.2222...$ discrepancy arise? Under what circumstances would $k$ divided by the expected value simply be the exact answer?

An intuitive approximation recognises that "reaching $k$" means the first time you hit $k$ or a higher value; the possibility of being higher than $k$ increases the expectation.  In your particular example of $n=2$ and $k=45$, the following stopping events are approximately equally likely:

being at a cumulative sum of $43$ and rolling a $2$ to reach $45$
being at a cumulative sum of $44$ and rolling a $1$ to reach $45$
being at a cumulative sum of $44$ and rolling a $2$ to reach $46$

so the expected cumulative sum when you stop is about $45+\frac13$
and when you divide this by the expected roll of $\frac32$ you get an expected number of rolls of about $30+\frac29$ as you have found.
Generalising this, the expected cumulative sum is about $k + \frac{n-1}{3}$ which when you divide by $\frac{n+1}{2}$ gives an expectation of about $\frac{2k}{n+1} + \frac{2(n-1)}{3(n+1)}$.  It is an approximation, but a good one when $k\gg n$.

of course! it seems extremely simple in hindsight. thank you.
